# Show date in dutch with FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

So i need to show the date in dutch with FPDF.
I tried "$this->setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl');" inbetween, before and after. but all of them just gives me an error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method PdfInvoice::setlocale() in C:\wamp\www\application\controllers\pdfinvoice.php on line 52"

What can i do now?

The code:

```
    $dateinvoice = substr( $invoice[ 'dateinvoice' ], 6 ).substr( $invoice[ 'dateinvoice' ], 3, 2 ).substr( $invoice[ 'dateinvoice' ], 0, 2 );
    $dateinvoice = date_create( $dateinvoice );
    $dateinvoice = false === $dateinvoice ? '' : $dateinvoice->format( 'd F Y' );
    $this->Cell( 10 ); $this->Cell( 40, 7, 'Datum' ); $this->Cell( 0, 7, $dateinvoice, 0, 1 );
```

Comment: Are you sure `$this->setlocale` is actually a method? Didn't you mean `setlocale()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Set locale to Dutch */
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');

/* Output: vrijdag 22 december 1978 */
echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 22, 1978));
```